# Quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

A quartic equation
$$x^4 +ax^3 +bx^2 +cx + d = 0$$
with real coefficients has exactly two distinct solutions, one of which is $1 +5i$.

Find the values of $a, b, c, d$.

I know that 1-5i is also a root because complex conjugates are roots. But I have no idea how to get to the final equation

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The double cubed term is _definitely_ a typo. Why were you so sure it wasn't?

Comment: If it's a typo then that makes it a lot easier then. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming real coefficients (you should edit that into your question), and fixing the silly double cubed terms, Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's hint is the way to go.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks quasi mate

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. Other than that, your post is wonderful. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). If you can make some quick fixes, then all will be well and I will undo my downvote. At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: if $$x=1+5i$$ is a solution, then $$x=1-5i$$ is also a solution

Comment: Isn't that assuming $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real?

Comment: yes i have assumed that all coefficients are real numbers